# Json returns different string

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My application is MVC 5 C#.
I am trying to get a string value from the controller using this Ajax script:

```
function testing() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../Home/Test",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: 1
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.PhotoURL) {
                    $("#Photo").html(result.PhotoURL);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the controller:

```
   public ActionResult Test(int id)
        {
            int updateid = 1;
            string thephoto = "<img src=\"@Url.Action(\"TheImage\",  
            new {id = " + updateid +
            "})\" class=\"mg-responsive\" style=\"margin-left: 
            auto;margin-right: auto\"/> ";
            var result = new
            {
                PhotoURL = thephoto
            };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I get:

```
   <img class="mg-responsive" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" 
src="@Url.Action(" {id='1})"' new="" thespillimage",="">
```

Comment: what were you hoping to get?

Comment: <img src=\"@Url.Action(\"TheImage\",  new {id = " + updateid +
                              "})\" class=\"mg-responsive\" style=\"margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto\"/>

Comment: That's exactly what your `Test()` method returns :). There is no point  using things like `@Url.Action` in a `string` - its razor code which is evaluated in the server and will not be evaluated in your script. Just return the actual url (use `string url = Url.Action(...);` to generate the url in the method

Comment: Thank you Stephen, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend returning the `updateid` first so that you can construct the img markup on the client side.

```
public ActionResult Test(int id)
    {
        int updateid = 1;
        var result = new
        {
            PhotoId = updateid
        };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And, on the client side

```
function testing() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Home/Test",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: 1
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.PhotoId) {
                var PhotoUrl = "<img src='/YourController/TheImage/" + result.PhotoId + " class='mg-responsive' style='margin-left:         auto;margin-right: auto'/> ";
                $("#Photo").html(PhotoURL);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

This saves the bandwidth and it is clean. If you want to change the class or properties attributes on the image you don't have to rebuild the solution.